# Highchart (stockchart) Yaxis on opposite side miss align when left axis is not visible

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart with **range selector** option. I have two yAxis. One is on the left side and the other one is on the right side.

> Left side Yaxis is invisible on load. And my right Y-axis is
>   overlapping with the graph.

If I change the left Y-axis to visible: true, then the alignment is correct. And this issue is not there in the 'highcharts'.

> It happens only with 'StockChart'

This is my javascript code,

```
    Highcharts.StockChart('container', {

    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: false,

        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
    [
      40,
      13
    ],
    [
      80,
      46
    ],
    [
      200,
      58
    ],
    [
      600,
      12
    ],
    [
      2000,
      46
    ],
],
visible: false,
    }, {
        data: [
    [
      40,
      55
    ],
    [
      60,
      53
    ],
    [
      200,
      44
    ],
    [
      600,
      42
    ],
    [
      2000,
      41
    ],
],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

[And this is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/uadxth0e/11/)

Comment: Hi @hakkim, Could you explain your problem more precisely? I do not see any issues in your live example. Also, I do not see any differences between `chart` and `stockChart`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rm7e42gn/

Comment: @ppotaczek , While initializing highcharts in your demo, instead of 'charts' please use 'StockChart'. I have used the range selector in my demo. That time the right Yaxis overlapping with the chart. This is the github reported issue url, https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11612

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in Highstock. As a workaround you can hide the first series in `load` event:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            this.series[0].hide();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ec4d9qon/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#hide